# Check if token expired using this JWT library

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I've configured the token like this:

```
jwt.sign(
  {
    user: pick(user, ['_id', 'username'])
  },
  secret,
  {
    expiresIn: '2m'
  }
);
```

But when I want to check if the token was expired, this code doesn't work:

```
function isAuthenticated() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refreshToken');
  try {
    decode(token);
    const { exp } = decode(refreshToken);
    if (exp < (new Date().getTime() + 1) / 1000) {
      return false;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

The problem is this part:

```
if (exp < (new Date().getTime() + 1) / 1000) {
  return false;
}
```

new Date().getTime() + 1) / 1000 = 1531335468.113

exp = 1531334595

Because I don't know what format of time JWT uses...

How can I resolve this?

Comment: print the output of "new Date().getTime() + 1" and please post.

Comment: How are you decoding the token? If you're using a library, it'll validate the expiration of the token automatically (by default). E.g. jsonwebtoken: https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback

Comment: @RamonSnir with the library jsonwebtoken

Comment: @AndrésMontoya why not use jwt.verify, instead of jwt.decode? jwt.decode doesn't even verify that the token is signed correctly.

Comment: @RamonSnir Oh, well, I wanted to know how can I do that with decode xD

Comment: @RamonSnir I'm using jwt-decode on the browser and jsonwebtoken on the server,  the function isAuthenticated is from the client

Comment: The code looks fine to me, as do the numbers. can you be more precise than "doesn't work"? also, JWT stores times in seconds since epoch. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#page-6

Answer (score 223, accepted):

This is the answer:

```
if (Date.now() >= exp * 1000) {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: flawed as now() uses timezones

Comment: @lony it is not flawed, Date.now() and JWT expiration time both identify the time elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Comment: does return false mean that token is expired?

Comment: @kritiz Yes. Basically, if the Date.now() in milliseconds is greater or equal to the expiration time (converted to milliseconds).

Comment: why multiply exp by 1000?

Comment: @SpiffJekey-Green because the `exp` field is in seconds but `Date.now()` returns milliseconds.

Answer (score 52):

You should use [jwt.verify](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/master/README.md#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback). It will check if the token is expired.

[jwt.decode](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/master/README.md#jwtdecodetoken--options) should not be used if the source is not trusted as it doesn't check if the token is valid.

Comment: The function isAuthenticated works in the front-end.Anyway the solution was commented for me...

Comment: Oh ok but you don't receive the `expiresIn` with the token ?

Comment: But what is the purpose of `exp`?

Comment: @Roel exp is used in the frontend, it's used to set a timeout and log out the user or otherwise refresh the token. I didn't know we could simply use jwt.verify to check if the token has expired. It's stated in the docs that: "The callback is called with the decoded payload if the signature is valid and optional expiration, audience, or issuer are valid. If not, it will be called with the error.", so we could simply use if (jwt.verify(token, secret) to verify if it has expired.

Answer (score 52):

Function without the `jwt` library:

**Browser**

```
function isTokenExpired(token) {
  const base64Url = token.split(".")[1];
  const base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, "+").replace(/_/g, "/");
  const jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(
    atob(base64)
      .split("")
      .map(function (c) {
        return "%" + ("00" + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
      })
      .join("")
  );

  const { exp } = JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
  const expired = Date.now() >= exp * 1000
  return expired
}
```

Or simpler

```
function isTokenExpired(token) {
  const expiry = (JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]))).exp;
  return (Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000)) >= expiry;
}
```

Or a one-liner:

```
const isTokenExpired = token => Date.now() >= (JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]))).exp * 1000
```

**Node.js**

```
function isTokenExpired(token) {
  const payloadBase64 = token.split('.')[1];
  const decodedJson = Buffer.from(payloadBase64, 'base64').toString();
  const decoded = JSON.parse(decodedJson)
  const exp = decoded.exp;
  const expired = (Date.now() >= exp * 1000)
  return expired
}
```

Or a one-liner:

```
const isTokenExpired = (token) => (Date.now() >= JSON.parse(Buffer.from(token.split('.')[1], 'base64').toString()).exp * 1000)
```

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you for sharing :).

Comment: Great job.Well done.Thank you a lot.

Comment: Missing "()" after the "new Date" in the "simpler" answer

Comment: @AlissonNunes typeof (new Date) === typeof new Date()

Comment: Hi. I was wondering, what happens if the Token is generated in the server with the server time and we're using *Date().Now* in a browser with a different time zone.

Answer (score 17):

`verify` itself returns an error if expired. It is safer as [Gabriel said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292406/check-if-token-expired-in-jwt/51293404#51293404).

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

router.use((req, res, next) => {
  const token = yourJwtService.getToken(req) // Get your token from the request
  jwt.verify(token, 'your-secret', function(err, decoded) {
    if (err) throw new Error(err) // Manage different errors here (Expired, untrusted...)
    req.auth = decoded // If no error, token info is returned in 'decoded'
    next()
  });
})
```

Answer (score 8):

Sadly, [Andrés Montoya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292406/check-if-token-expired-in-jwt/51293316#51293316) has a flaw which is related to how he compares the object.

I found a solution [here](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode/issues/53) which should solve this:

```
const now = Date.now().valueOf() / 1000

if (typeof decoded.exp !== 'undefined' && decoded.exp < now) {
    throw new Error(`token expired: ${JSON.stringify(decoded)}`)
}
if (typeof decoded.nbf !== 'undefined' && decoded.nbf > now) {
    throw new Error(`token expired: ${JSON.stringify(decoded)}`)
}
```

Thanks to user *[thejohnfreeman](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode/issues/53#issuecomment-413069022)*!

Answer (score 5):

The following function works without any libraries:

```
function getJWTExpireDate(jwtToken: string) {
  if (jwtToken) {
    try {
      const [, payload] = jwtToken.split('.');
      const { exp: expires } = JSON.parse(window.atob(payload));
      if (typeof expires === 'number') {
        return new Date(expires * 1000);
      }
    } catch {
      // ignore
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

**Don't use this to check whether the token is valid.** One good use case is displaying when the token expires in the frontend.

Answer (score 5):

Client side

```
const JWT = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjEyMzQ1Njc4OTAsIm5hbWUiOiJKb2huIERvZSIsImlhdCI6MTUxNjIzOTAyMn0.1c_yQjnMZfKUb4UTDE_WvbC71f8xxtyMsdqKKkI1hF8";

const jwtPayload = JSON.parse(window.atob(JWT.split('.')[1]))
const isExpired = Date.now() >= jwtPayload.exp * 1000;
```

Comment: !!!If you are looking for client side check this is the best answer!!! +1

Answer (score 1):

some answers omit verification step which is super dangerous!

### safe replacement for `jwt.verify` with following changes

- it does **NOT** throw when token is expired, but does throw for invalid token.
- return object is `{payload, expired}` instead of `payload`

##### js version

```js
export function verifyJWT(token) {
  try {
    return { payload: jwt.verify(token, publicKey), expired: false };
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.name == "TokenExpiredError") {
      return { payload: jwt.decode(token), expired: true };
    }
    throw error;
  }
}
```

##### ts version

```
export function verifyJWT(token: string) {
  try {
    return { payload: jwt.verify(token, publicKey), expired: false };
  } catch (error) {
    if ((error as Error).name == "TokenExpiredError") {
      return { payload: jwt.decode(token), expired: true };
    }
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for [React Native](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)#React_Native), but login will work for all types.

```
isTokenExpired = async () => {
    try {
        const LoginTokenValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('LoginTokenValue');
        if (JSON.parse(LoginTokenValue).RememberMe) {
            const { exp } = JwtDecode(LoginTokenValue);
            if (exp < (new Date().getTime() + 1) / 1000) {
                this.handleSetTimeout();
                return false;
            } else {
                //Navigate inside the application
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            //Navigate to the login page
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Spalsh -> isTokenExpired -> err', err);
        //Navigate to the login page
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *jwt* verify method to check the validity of your token. *err* means the token is expired and will throw an error so you can remove the stored token.

```
 jwt.verify(token, SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
          localStorage.clear();
      }}
  });
```

Comment: Hi, how is it possible to remove that specific token for that user , since the information for getting the user is stored in the token which I can't get since it throws an error ?

Answer (score -4):

```
// Pass in function expiration date to check token 
function checkToken(exp) {
    if (Date.now() <= exp * 1000) {
      console.log(true, 'token is not expired')
    } else { 
      console.log(false, 'token is expired') 
    }
  }
```