# Email verification MERN stack app fails to handle wrong or expired token

Tags: reactjs, mern, email-validation

I'm trying to implement email verification in a MERN stack app, and while a big deal of it works, I'm struggling to handle the case when the token is either invalid or expired.

To try and be brief, this is more or less what happens:

**User registers**

Towards the end of the registration function (backend) I have:

```js
// Create user
const user = new User({
  name,
  email,
  password: hashedPassword,
});

// Email verification
jwt.sign(
  {
    user: user._id,
  },
  process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  {
    expiresIn: 3600,
  },
  (err, emailToken) => {
    mailTransport().sendMail({
      from: process.env.USER_EMAIL,
      to: user.email,
      subject: 'Verify your email address',
      html: generateEmail(emailToken),
    });
  }
);

await user.save();
```

The function `generateEmail()` creates and emails a verification link such as:

`${process.env.FRONTEND}/verify-email/${token}`

The React component in the frontend, `VerifyEmail.jsx` is roughly like this (deleted redundant code):

```
const API_URL = '/api/users/verify-email';

const VerifyEmail = () => {
  const { verificationToken } = useParams();

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const onVerify = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.get(`${API_URL}/${verificationToken}`);

      toast.success('Email verified. You can now log in');
      navigate('/login');
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <h1 className="text-6xl border-b-2 pb-2">Verify your email</h1>
      <p className="my-5">Please click below to verify your email</p>
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-info" onClick={onVerify}>
        Verify Email
      </button>
    </section>
  );
};
```

The backend route for that request is:

```js
router.get('/verify-email/:verificationToken', verifyToken);
```

And the function `verifyToken` is:

```js
const verifyToken = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { user } = jwt.verify(
      req.params.verificationToken,
      process.env.JWT_SECRET
    );

    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user, { verified: true }, { new: true });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error(error.message);
  }
  return res.redirect(process.env.FRONTEND);
});
```

All this effectively verifies the email and updates the user in the database with `verified: true` **BUT** it doesn't handle when the token is invalid or expired.

What am I missing?

Need to add that the only error I get is, in the console, a `400` saying I'm attempting a `GET` request on the API on the frontend (port 3000) rather than the backend (5001):

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/users/verify-email/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoiNjFmZDUyNzFhNzIyMjNjZWE4MGM0MDcxIiwiaWF0IjoxNjQzOTkxNjY1LCJleHAiOjE2NDM5OTUyNjV9.zyWhGtfV2coNZKYVW6yUOUbHo6gBnZZ4aRU79OE0Nbw
```

(Only when the JWT is expired or invalid)

Comment: Try adding await for the jwt.verify and check

Comment: That doesn't solve it, and there's no issue when the token is valid.

Comment: Check this if it helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292406/check-if-token-expired-using-this-jwt-library

Comment: Thank you, but my `.verify()` indeed creates the error. The issue is the handling of it, in which I'm failing and don't know how to do it properly.